# Header height changes in jQuery mobile in response to click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, nativedroid

I have a page in a jQuery mobile phonegap application, and it behaves strangely. Whenever I click the body (content) the header increases is height. From examining the elements, it seems the H1 title moves to the right and bottom in response to the click, increasing its distance from the icon on the left. I use jquery mobile 1.3.2, with [nativeDroid 2.2.0](http://nativedroid.godesign.ch). My code is as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="feedbackPage" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Feedback</h1>
        <a href="#feedbackPagePanel" data-icon='reorder' data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <form>
            <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="feedback" id="feedback"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" name="submitfeedback" id="submitfeedback">Send</button>
        </form>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="panel" id="feedbackPagePanel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-icon="home"><a href="#homePage">Home</a></li>
            <li data-icon="envelope"><a href="#feedbackPage">Feedback</a></li>
            <li data-icon="cog"><a href="#settingsPage">Settings</a></li>
            <li data-icon="info"><a href="#aboutPage">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->
</div>
```

It happens on other pages as well, even though they contain listview (with static content, not links).

Here is how the page should look like:

[image: Good behavior]

Here is what happens after clicking on the text. Notice the title has moved to the right and bottom

[image: Bad behavior]

A second click restores the size to the original position. How I can I prevent this?

Comment: you have an extra `</p>` after `</form>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQM seems to toggle a class called ui-fixed-hidden in the header when you click the text.  Try adding the following CSS to override that added padding:

```
.ui-header.ui-fixed-hidden {
    padding: 0;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.ui-header-fixed > .ui-btn-icon-notext{
    top:6px
}
```

UPDATE: added css to keep icon in place, and fixed bottom border CSS to keep width constant.
Here is a fiddle demo:  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/aay52/)**

UPDATE 2:

Instead of the CSS fix above, you can try the `data-tap-toggle="false"` attribute on your header, or in javascript:

```
$( ".selector" ).fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
```

Here is the API documentation:http://api.jquerymobile.com/fixedtoolbar/#option-tapToggle
and here is the updated demo: **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/aay52/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The H1 remains constant, but now the blue line changes its width (become thinner) and the menu icon moves to bottom - about 2 pixels.

Comment: I have found this in the jquerymobile css .ui-header-fixed.ui-fixed-hidden>.ui-btn-icon-notext{top:6px}. Setting the same out the ui-fixed-hidden (.ui-header-fixed>.ui-btn-icon-notext{top:6px}) keeps the icon in place, but the blue line keeps flickering

Comment: David, I have updated my answer above.  Change border-bottom-width in my original CSS to 2px to maintain the blue line thickness.

Comment: David, i recently figured out (answering another question) that you can just apply data-tap-toggle="false" to your header and leave the CSS alone.  See updated answer above and the updated fiddle.

Comment: I've already used data-tap-toggle="false" but I still having the problem, any other hint to solve it?