# Header and footer height changes in jquery mobile when using forms

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, nativedroid

I'm new to jQuery and to mobile applications in general.

I have an annoying problem with a jQuery theme called nativeDroid.
After adding forms to my page, whenever I click on the form (regular input or textarea) the 
header and footer changes their location and stretches the page width. 
It seems that when clicking on the text filed, another class is added to the header div. 
the class name is .ui-fixed-hidden.

I viewed an identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957133/header-height-changes-in-jquery-mobile-in-response-to-click/19960667#19960667?newreg=02289936589b4175bace56026a296776) but the solution isn't working for me.
I tried changing the .ui-fixed-hidden class so that it matches the solution given but the
problem remains the same. If any one can help me I would really appreciate it since it will
be a shame to give up such a great looking theme like this one.

I can't post any images yet but the problem looks identical to the one in the post I added.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: try and add this ----  data-position="fixed"  -- to your header and footer

Comment: this is the normal behavior of fixed toolbars, they get [unfixed](http://api.jquerymobile.com/toolbar/#option-hideDuringFocus) when `input` or `textarea` are focused.

Answer (score 1):

I am using PrimeFaces 5.0 final release, which means I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.

I added data-tap-toggle="false" as recommended here (and in many other questions here on stackoverflow), but that did not solve my issue.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

So, I also added the following, and this fixes my issue.

```
.ui-header.ui-fixed-hidden {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  data-tap-toggle="false"

For example, i used in this header, and worked for me:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="height:87px" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a href="#grid-menu" class="botonHeader" data-theme="b" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <img src="objetos/logo_48.jpg" class="ui-btn-right logoHeader"/>
</div>
```

This has to do with the tap toggle function. When you click on the page, we set position: absolute; instead of fixed for the toolbars. You will notice this behaviour on this page that has more content: http://jsbin.com/erezak/25
So removing/adding that class is on purpose. If you don't want this you can set data-tap-toggle="false".

The problem is that we pull fixed footers 1px down to fix a 1px gap issue on Android. We also set 1px padding-bottom to keep the same visual height.
This is causing the text to jump 1px when we switch to position: absolute; on a short page (no scroll)

Other issue is that the border is not visible with position: fixed;, but becomes visible with position: absolute;

Ref: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ui-fixed-hidden-on-click-event-1-1-rc2